# Automatically create subfolders by date and move files into subfolder at the end of the day

Tags: script, echo

I use the software iSpy to record audio and I have set it up to save the recordings to a folder. The problem is that there is no organization at all, so I have thousands of audio recordings in one folder.

My goal would be to set up a folder structure that organizes by date and moves all files that have been created / modified (note: the creation date is not the same as the modification date, so if there is a difference in script, I'd like both available please.) at the end of the day.

The folder location is: M:\Security Software\iSpy\audio\VHCEX

This is an example file name:1_2016-04-19_14-06-02.mp3

or 1_YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM-SS.mp3

In my research, I came across the following scripts [[source]](http://community.ispyconnect.com/ispybb2/viewtopic.php?t=595#p4376)

```
@echo off
for /d %%i in (*) do (
cd %%i
call :doMove
cd ..
)
echo Really Done
goto eof:
pause




:doMove
echo Moving files... Please wait...
for /F "tokens=1-3,4* delims=-_" %%a in ('dir /b *.avi') do (
title Processing %%b-%%c-%%d_%%e
if not exist ".\%%b\%%c\%%d" (
 mkdir ".\%%b\%%c\%%d"
 echo New Date: \%%b\%%c\%%d
)
if exist "%%a_%%b-%%c-%%d_%%e" move "%%a_%%b-%%c-%%d_%%e" ".\%%b\%%c\%%d\%%e"
if exist "%%a_%%b_%%c-%%d-%%e" move "%%a_%%b_%%c-%%d-%%e" ".\%%b\%%c\%%d\%%e"
)
for /F "tokens=1-3,4* delims=-_" %%a in ('dir /b *.mp4') do (
title Processing %%b-%%c-%%d_%%e
if not exist ".\%%b\%%c\%%d" mkdir ".\%%b\%%c\%%d"
if exist "%%a_%%b-%%c-%%d_%%e" move "%%a_%%b-%%c-%%d_%%e" ".\%%b\%%c\%%d\%%e"
if exist "%%a_%%b_%%c-%%d-%%e" move "%%a_%%b_%%c-%%d-%%e" ".\%%b\%%c\%%d\%%e"
)

echo Moving Thumbs
for /F "tokens=1-3,4* delims=-_" %%a in ('dir /b thumbs\*.jpg') do (
title Processing %%b-%%c-%%d_%%e
if exist "thumbs\%%a_%%b-%%c-%%d_%%e" move "thumbs\%%a_%%b-%%c-%%d_%%e" ".\%%b\%%c\%%d\%%e"
if exist "thumbs\%%a_%%b_%%c-%%d-%%e" move "thumbs\%%a_%%b_%%c-%%d-%%e" ".\%%b\%%c\%%d\%%e"
)



title Done.
:EOF
```

I also found a Perl script [[source]](http://community.ispyconnect.com/ispybb2/viewtopic.php?t=595#p2710)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use File::stat;
use File::Copy;
use POSIX;
use Mail::Sendmail;
use Date::Calc qw(:all);

my $oldest_week = 4;
my $delete_week = 1;
my $move_count = 0;
my $delete_count = 0;

my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime;

$year += 1900;
$mon += 1;

my ($current_week,$current_year) = Week_of_Year($year, $mon, $mday);

my @folders = ("D:/iSpy/video/Front Door",
               "D:/iSpy/video/Front Path",
               "D:/iSpy/video/Garden",
               "D:/iSpy/video/Lounge",
               "D:/iSpy/video/Patio",
               "D:/iSpy/video/Shed");

foreach (@folders)

{
    my $viddir=$_;

    print "$viddir\n\n";

    opendir("curdir",$viddir)||die("Cannot open Directory!");

    my @names=readdir("curdir");

    foreach (@names)

    {

      my $name=$_;
      my $source = $viddir."/".$name;
      my $upname=uc($name);
      my $pos_avi=index($upname,".AVI");
      my $pos_mp4=index($upname,".MP4");

      if ($pos_avi > 0 or $pos_mp4 > 0)  

        { 

        ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime (stat($source)->mtime);

        $year += 1900;
        $mon += 1;

        my ($week,$year) = Week_of_Year($year, $mon, $mday);

        print "file $source was updated on $year $mon $mday - that was week $week - ";

        my $target="$viddir/$week";

        print "Move to folder $viddir/$week\n";

        move($source,$target);

        $move_count ++;

        }
    }
}

if ($oldest_week >= $current_week) {
  $delete_week = 52 + $current_week - $oldest_week;
} else {
    $delete_week = $current_week - $oldest_week;
}

@folders = ("D:/iSpy/video/Front Door/$delete_week",
            "D:/iSpy/video/Front Path/$delete_week",
            "D:/iSpy/video/Garden/$delete_week",
            "D:/iSpy/video/Lounge/$delete_week",
            "D:/iSpy/video/Patio/$delete_week",
            "D:/iSpy/video/Shed/$delete_week");

foreach (@folders)

{
    my $delete_dir=$_;

    opendir("curdir",$delete_dir)||die("Cannot open Directory!");

    my @names=readdir("curdir");

    foreach (@names) {

      my $name=$_;
      my $target = "$delete_dir/$name";
      my $upname=uc($name);
      my $pos_avi=index($upname,".AVI");
      my $pos_mp4=index($upname,".MP4");

      if ($pos_avi > 0 or $pos_mp4 > 0)  

        { 

        print "file to delete is $target\n";
        unlink $target;
        $delete_count ++;

        }
    }
}

my $mail_body = "$move_count moved";

if ($delete_count > 0) {
$mail_body = $mail_body . ", $delete_count deleted from folder $delete_week\n";   
}
print "$mail_body\n";

my %mail = (
                    To      => 'name@somewhere.com',
                    From    => 'iSpy@anywhere.com',   
                    Subject => 'Daily iSpy Recordings Move / Delete',
                    Message => $mail_body,
                    'content-type' => 'text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"',
                    'X-Mailer' => "Mail::Sendmail version $Mail::Sendmail::VERSION",
                    );

$mail{Smtp} = 'smtp.anywhere.com';

if (sendmail %mail) { print "Mail sent OK.\n\n" }
else { print "Error sending mail: $Mail::Sendmail::error \n" }
```

Both do need to be tweaked to suit my specific case, but I'm not sure how to edit either one.

Comment: What is wrong with existing scripts?

Comment: The cmd window just opens and closes instantly. I did edit the script to take into account that the file extensions had to be .mp3 (forgot to add that extension in the OP, but fixed it).